razorpay double modal, double text and not responding in test mode
I think Razorpay is updating the frontend of the modal and is totally unresponsive in nature. On opening, I am getting double modals as well as double text whenever I write in any of the fields present there.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
